# How to debug Express.js app with WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I am currently developing Express.js application which I suppose to use as an API for my Angular application. I need to debug Express app with WebStorm.

Can any one help me to figure out how to make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webstorm has a native debugging tool for node.js, including breakpoints, call stack, in-editor expressions evaluation etc. You can find the exact explanation in the 
[following link to jetbrains' blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm/), including specific example for an express application.